# Linq aggregate from Dictionary

Tags: vb.net, linq, dictionary

I have a dictionary of T, and i want to get the multiplication of a range of the collection based on a predicate

In particular i have a Dictionary Of Key (String) with an Average (integer) and Data (integer)
I want to multiplicate the Data of all Elements that have an Average > 6

```
Class Classroom
  Sub New(ByVal NewData As Integer, ByVal NewAverage As Integer)
    Average = NewAverage
    Data = NewData
  End Sub

  Dim Data As Integer
  Dim Average As Integer
End Class

Dim Elements As New Dictionary(Of String, Classroom)
Elements.Add("Simon", New Classroom( 6, 5))
Elements.Add("Jennifer", New Classroom(7, 7))
Elements.Add("Timoty", New Classroom(8, 4))
Elements.Add("Janet", New Classroom(7, 6))
```

I tried this Linq expression, but it doesn't works

```
Dim Result as Integer = Elements.Where(Function(minAverage) minAverage.Value.Average > 6).Aggregate(Fuction(x, y) x.Value.Data * y.Value.Data)
```

Comment: How is it not working? Do you get an exception? The wrong answer?

Comment: Impossible to convert Integer Value into System.Collections.Generic.KeyValuePair(Of String, Classroom)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `Aggregate` function returns a single, aggregated, object of the same type as all the other items in the list.  In other words, if you use `Aggregate` on a list of persons, it will return a person.  If you use it on a list of animals, it will return an animal.  Etc.  Since you are using it on a `Dictionary(Of String, Classroom)`, which is a list of `KeyValuePair(Of String, Classroom)`, that means the aggregate will be of that type, not an `Integer`, as your code is expecting.

To make it work properly, you need to do one of two things.  Either you need to fix the lambda in your Aggregate function so that it returns a `KeyValuePair(Of String, Classroom)` (and fix the `Result` variable as well), or you need to add a `Select` method to transform the list into something simpler *before* calling `Aggregate`.  Since you aren't using any of the other data in the list in the aggregating lambda it seems like the latter is the more appropriate approach.  So, for instance:

```
Dim Result As Integer = Elements.
    Where(Function(pair) pair.Value.Average > 6).
    Select(Function(pair) pair.Value.Data).
    Aggregate(Function(x, y) x * y)
```

Comment: Thanks Steven, very good explanation and simple to understand